# Hiding a selection based on another selection in an ssrs report

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I need to write an SSRS report that displays data based on user selected options (parameters).  The report will be run on either paid or unpaid data.  If the selection is for unpaid data, the report does not need a date value (it will select all the unpaid records in the database).  However, if the user selects paid data, they should also put in a date range.  Is there a way to either hide or disable the date parameters if the user selects unpaid data?

I have found several forums that indicate this isn't possible, but want to verify with the folks here on stackoverflow (I have a higher level of confidence with the responses here).  I also looked at cascading parameters but this doesn't seem to fit that mold.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If it helps here is what type of data will be included in the report: Account Number, Client, phone number, email address.  This data will be consistent regardless of whether the client selects paid or unpaid.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think you would need to write custom report viewer app for that kind of functionality.

Comment: You can not hide the date range perameter but put a default value in date range for (unpaid) so use does not have to enter, using dynamic perameter. otherwise i agree with @kyooryu and you have to create custom report viewer or asp page.